# exported object returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have file **main.js**-

```
import Maze from "./mazeContainer.js";

let MyMaze;
....
initiate();
....
function initiate() {
    MyMaze = new Maze(Ctx, Width, Height, CustomGrid[0].value, CustomGrid[1].value);
    MyMaze.setup();
    listenMoves();
}
....
export default MyMaze.player;
```

When I `import` Player in another file, the `Player` is **undefined**.

To say where I define `MyMaze.player`, it's  inside `Maze` class-

```
class Maze(arguments....) {
    ....
    setup() {
        ....
        this.drawMap();
    }
    drawMap() {
        ....
        this.player = new Player();
        this.player.setPlayer();
    }
    ....
}
```

Before this, I had everything inside the same file, and everything was working well. Now when I want to export `MyMaze.player` to **move-detection.js**. But here in **move-detection.js**

```
import Player from "./main.js";
```

`Player` doesn't seem to be defined.

[image]

I guess I'm doing something wrong with the `export`. What's the issue with it?
Here's the link to project- https://codesandbox.io/s/maze-p2pyo

Comment: I don't think you can export an instance method.

Comment: The important part of the code is not shown here. The Maze class should be the issue here if MyMaze.player is not defined at the bottom.

Comment: @Edub I can't seem to find an error with MyMaze. I've edited my question with provided link.

Comment: That page just shows me "Loading Sandbox
Fetching git repository..." and nothing more seems to happen (Firefox/Windows).

Comment: The link  is working well for me (I also use firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I figured out the reason for `MyMaze.player` not having been defined by the time compiler reaches the `export` statement at the end of **main.js**. You see when I call `initiate()`-

```
function initiate() {
    MyMaze = new Maze(Ctx, Width, Height, CustomGrid[0].value, CustomGrid[1].value);
    MyMaze.setup();
    listenMoves();
}
```

Now `MyMaze.setup()`, after it's performed its job, calls `drawMap()`-

```
setup() {
    ....
    this.drawMap();
}
```

And lastly, `drawMap()` was using `requestAnimationFrame()` for each iteration-

```
drawMap() {
    ....
    if (this.stack.length === 0) {
        // set player
        this.player = new Player(this);
        this.player.setPlayer();
    }
    ....
    window.requestAnimationFrame(()=> this.drawMap());
}
```

And here's the reason for the issue- `requestAnimationFrame()`.

As `requestAnimationFrame()` is **asynchronous**, this means that after `drawMap` is run for the first time, the execution goes out to `listenMoves()`-

```
function initiate() {
    ....
    listenMoves();
}
```

> ***So while `drawMap()` is still running and `player` has not been setup yet, the execution reaches to the end of **main.js*****-

```
export default MyMaze.player;
```

And this gives me-

> TypeError: undefined has no properties

The fix was to either drop `requestAnimationFrame()` and directly call `this.drawMap()`

**or** instantiate `player`inside `setup()` before `drawMap()` gets called.

**I hope I'm made the correct assumption! Cheers!**

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (this.stack.length === 0) {
        this.goal = this.currentCell;
        this.drawGoal(this.goal);

        // set player
        this.player = new Player(this);
        this.player.setPlayer();

        // remove Preparing Screen
        document.querySelector(".resetting-grid").classList.remove("show");
        return;
    }
```

That's the condition to set the player. The stack is initialized with [] and not filled in the process - drawMap() is called but will not go into the condition to set the player. So it's expected to hit an undefined value.

Not sure about the code but I would initialize the player in the setup() method and only set the player in the condition. Not sure about the rest of the code and assumptions made about an present/absent player object.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you changed, this `if` statement doesn't include anything different than mine.

Comment: Yeah project has changed so much in the meantime can't really figure it out anymore. My  assumuption might have been wrong about the ordering of the imports and the state of this.stack.length.